# Proof Check: Unique Continuation of Analytic Functions

Tags: proof-verification, analyticity

Here is the theorem I have been attempting to prove, I would love to hear some feedback on it!

**Theorem:**

Suppose $\Omega$ is a connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $f$ is a real analytic function on $\Omega$ and $f=0$ on a non empty open subset of $\Omega$. Then $f\equiv 0$ in $\Omega$.

**Proof:**

Let $\omega$ be the interior (definition 2.3.4) of $\{x\in\Omega : f(x)=0\}$. Then $\omega$ is open, and by the assumption, it is non-empty. Let $a\in\Omega$ be a limit point of $\omega$ (definition 2.3.5). As $f$ is real analytic everywhere in $\Omega$, it is real analytic at the limit point $a\in \Omega$. Meaning that the power series expansion of $f$ about the point $a$ is convergent in some neighbourhood of $a$. Now, any neighbourhood of $a$ must intersect $\omega$, and $f$ is identically zero in $\omega$. Now, all derivatives vanish of infinite order in the interior of $\omega$, so by continuity all derivatives must vanish of infinite order at the point $a$. Therefore, it must be that $f=0$ on a neighbourhood of $a$, which implies that $a\in \omega$. Since $\omega$ contains all of its limit points in $\Omega$, it is relatively closed. However, it was stated earlier that $\omega$ is an open set of $\Omega$. Hence, $\omega$ is clopen in $\Omega$.

Since $\omega$ is clopen in the connected space $\Omega$, and it is non-empty, it must be that $\omega=\Omega$ (by proposition 2.3.1).

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks so much!

Comment: Even if you've already gotten an answer to your question, it can't hurt to leave it on the site so that other people might benefit from reading your proof! (Though it would have been better to edit your original question instead of posting two more about the same problem...)

Comment: If the domain of $f$ is an arbitrary connected topological space $\Omega$, then there is no such condition as "$f$ is a real analytic function". In order to talk about analyticity and power series, you need a lot more structure on $\Omega$ than "connected topological space". Perhaps you mean "$\Omega$ is a connected open subset of $\Bbb R^n$?".

Comment: $\omega$ is only the interior of $f^{-1}(0)$, so $f(a) = 0$ does not imply that $a \in \omega$. For that you have to show that $f$ is zero on an entire neighborhood of $a$ (analyticity implies this, provided $\omega \ne \emptyset$, but you didn't include that part in your proof).

Comment: @PaulSinclair I will edit this proof now, it would be great if you could tell me whether or not I have corrected it. Thank you

Comment: If $\Omega$ is just a connected topological space, and $f$ is defined on certain subset of $\Omega$, what is meant by $f$ is analytic?

Comment: As Danny Pak-Keung Chan has noticed, you still haven't fixed the problem that $\Omega$ has to be something that analyticity is definable on. As I said above, "connected topological space" is not sufficient. Also, you need to note that that $f^{(k)}$ being $0$ on $\omega$ implies it is $0$ at $a$ *because $a$ is on the boundary of $\omega$*. And it is not just $f(a) = 0$ that implies $a \in \omega$, but rather that $f = 0$ on a neighborhood of $a$. Adding the definition references isn't helpful in my opinion - these are well-known. But you know better what your teacher wants.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think I may of fixed it

Comment: The theorem statement should say that $f$ is analytic on $\Omega$. Currently there is nothing linking $f$ to $\Omega$. The rest is just improving the write-up: $\omega$ is not "the non-empty open set" - any such set will do to satisfy the hypothesis. Instead it is open because the interior is open by definition, and it is non-empty because it must contain the non-empty open set of the hypothesis. Usually, you would just say something like "Let $\omega$ be the interior of $\{x\in\Omega : f(x) = 0\}$. Then $\omega$ is open, and by the assumption, it is non-empty."

Comment: The phrase "We now know that $f=0$ at any arbitrary limit point $a$ of $\omega$, and" is not necessary to your argument. You should remove it. The remainder of the sentence is what you need. There is also no need to repeat the definition of $\omega$ at the end of the proof. This proof is too short for people to have forgotten it. Just conclude that since $\omega$ contains all of it's limit points in $\Omega$, it is relatively closed. (It can have limit points in $\Bbb R^n$ that it doesn't contain, as long as they aren't in $\Omega$. As a subspace of $\Omega$, it is closed).

Comment: And your final paragraph is also too wordy. Just conclude that since $\omega$ is clopen in the connected space $\Omega$, and is non-empty, it must be equal to $\Omega$  "by proposition 2.3.1".

Comment: @JS26 Why not cover $\Omega$ by open balls where $f$ is represented by the Taylor series at the center. If two balls intersect, we can add finitely many such balls such that the center of $B_i$ lies in $B_{i-1}$. Finally any finite length curve $\subset \Omega$ is compact thus covered by finitely many such balls, so "identically zero" propagates from one ball to all the others.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you, after thinking about it a bit more and going through each step it all makes a lot more sense now. I've refined the theorem and the proof and tried to condense it a bit.

Comment: @reuns - the connected argument is simpler. The main concept of this proof - that since the taylor series is zero on some open set, it has to be zero everywhere, is still necessary for your proof. But here, after that is shown, it is only a couple more sentences to get the entire result.

Comment: @JS26 - now I'll echo Robert Shore. It looks good to me.

Comment: I don't agree. The main point of analytic functions is that any compact is covered by finitely many Taylor series.

Comment: @PaulSinclair , I am using this proof in a university submission, using stack exchange for some guidance doesn’t count as plaigarism does it?

Comment: If it does, then pretty much everyone is guilty. The basic idea here was yours. I just gave you pointers for cleaning up your theorem statement and argument. Such assistance is pretty standard for these submissions. Also, this is a well-known result, and this is probably the most common proof of it. You can hardly avoid being derivative here. So while they are expecting you to think it out yourself instead of just copying some proof, they are not looking for complete originality.